# Python framework to use with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, frameworks, web, turbogears2

I was planning on starting a project using Turbogears 2. I noticed however that in particular on stackoverflow.com there don't seem to be many questions concerning it. According to Wikipedia, it seems the framework is still under active development (the last stable version released 50 days ago or so). I selected TG2 mostly because of it's support for SQLAlchemy that I find a superior ORM solution for my needs.

**Questions**:

- Would you consider TG2 as a framework with a future or rather a dying technology?
- Would you recommend using it for a new project considering the answer to the previous question?
- If the answer is "no", what other Python frameworks similar to TG2 (in particular: highly modular, integrated with SQLAlchemy), are there?

Hope these won't be classified as "open-ended" questions. Cheers!

Comment: I hope an old answer of mine helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013741/what-should-i-worry-about-python-template-engines-and-web-frameworks/12013995#12013995

Comment: Still no other asnwers since?
Maybe you could select mine as the good one ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely go for [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/)

It is highly modular and has native "scaffold" to use SqlAlchemy as ORM.

You can also combine SqlAlchemy with [FormAlchemy](https://github.com/FormAlchemy/formalchemy) which is the forms system built on top of SqlAlchemy.

The same developper released [pyramid_formalchemy](https://github.com/FormAlchemy/pyramid_formalchemy) module to help you setting all this together.

Comment: Yea, this looks better. At least it has a rising curve in google trends

Comment: Pyramid merges ideas from Turbogears, since Turgogears joined the Pylons project last year. It is built on Pylons, Turbogears, repoze.bfg, and others like Zope.
I was a huge Django fan, but Pyramid is what I switched to since last month.
I also noticed that it is rising.

Comment: Please keep in mind that TurboGears actually didn't join the Pylons project. There has been some discussion about doing it but in the end it didn't happen. TurboGears project is still under development, the two upcoming minor and major releases will be 2.2.1 and 2.3 with 2.3 providing support for Python3, huge speed ups and the ability to create single file turbogears applications.

Comment: So what is the relation between Pyramid and TurboGears? When to choose which one?

Comment: Went with Pyramid and I'm really satisfied with the choice. Great modularity.